# Cadence Question: what does # mean in below fomular: ((frame>>word(bit_index))&2#1?

Tags: vb.net, cadence

I'm reviewing some cadence test program and wondering what does # means in below formula:
It is to count the total 1 bit in frame data,
Thanks! Appreciate your time!

```
total_one_bit = 0
for bit_index = 0 to 15 do
    total_one_bit = total_one_bit + ((frame>>word(bit_index))&2#1)
endfor
```

Comment: That code isn't VB.NET. Did you intend to add some tag other than vb.net?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I'd presume it's the "cadence" tag that applies to what's posted.

Comment: thanks for your reply!